# What's the difference between IC 74HC04 and IC 74AC04PC?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, diodes, breadboard

I am trying to make a simple logic gate simulation for which I require the former IC but I could only procure the latter. Will it still work?

Comment: What do you see when you compare the datasheets?

Comment: Agree a link to the data sheets is at least the minimum amount of effort on your part.

Comment: Yeah I checked the data sheets, both are Hex Inverters.    http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-304/54528.pdf                                         http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-309/66862.pdf

Comment: But when I'm connecting it with the breadboard, I can see my Input LED glow, but not the output one. I think there is no current passing through the Output resistance and therefore no current through the LED.

Comment: Circuit diagram?

Comment: http://www.pyroelectro.com/files/edu/digital/logic_gates/schematics.pdf These are the circuit diagrams for the three logic gates I'm doing.

Comment: OK for blinking LED's it shouldn't matter.  Does it work with one and not the other?  What are your R values?  Are the LED's in the right way?

Comment: Well the local supplier only has the 74AC04PC so I couldn't try it out with the other one, with which it is supposed to work.

Comment: For what you're trying to do, either version will work, but how are you supplying the input signal to the circuit?  That is, are you supplying +5V for a logic high and then letting the input float for a logic low or are you grounding the input?

Answer (score 2):

The 74AC04 is faster than the 74HC04. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family#Monolithic_integrated_circuit_logic_families_compared) lists a typical delay of 3ns for the AC family and 9ns for the HC family. Comparing the two datasheets one lists 4ns, the other lists 9ns. The "PC" in the AC's part number is just a package code.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming no wiring missteaks or missing smoke:

1. in the diagram with the AND as the DUT, when either X or Y are high, their respective LEDs will light, but the output LED will only light when X AND Y are **BOTH** high.
2. In the diagram with the inverter as the DUT, when Y is high its LED will light, but the output LED will NOT.  Conversely, when Y is low the input LED will not be lit, but the output LED will be.  Your issue, perhaps?
3. in the diagram with the OR as the DUT, when either X OR Y is high, its respective LED and the output LED will be lit.  Otherwise - when X and Y are **BOTH** low - their respective LEDs and the output LED will be off.

Comment: It is likely that the LED plus resistor on the inputs will not pull the input low enough to be recognized as a low.  Add 10K resistors from each input pin to ground in parallel with the LED/resistor already there, to ensure that the input is recognized as a low when not pulled high.

Comment: That'll work, but shouldn't be necessary, since CMOS inputs aren't allowed to float.  That being the case, the inputs to the devices under test should be either a solid Vcc or a solid GND. Besides that, the OP doesn't report trouble on the inputs, but on the outputs.